# HTML5 Image upload with javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I want to multi-upload images to a  database using `javascript` and `php` (html5), but I have problem with it, my code is just uploading one image, which is the latest photo selected and not all. How can fix this problem and what do I have to do?

I use developer mozilla html5: **[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)**

You can test my code by selecting multi images and clicking on button `Upload Image` to see the result.

**[DEMO FROM MY FULL CODDE](http://binboy.gigfa.com/imgup.html)**

My js code:

```
function doClick() {
    var el = document.getElementById("fileElem");
    if (el) {
        el.click();
    }
}

function handleFiles(files) {
    var d = document.getElementById("fileList");
    if (!files.length) {
        d.innerHTML = "<p>No files selected!</p>";
    } else {
        var list = document.createElement("ul");
        d.appendChild(list);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            list.appendChild(li);

            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);;
            img.height = 60;
            img.onload = function () {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
            }
            li.appendChild(img);

            var info = document.createElement("span");
            info.innerHTML = files[i].name + ": " + files[i].size + " bytes";
            li.appendChild(info);
        }
    }
}
```

My php code:

```
<?php 
  foreach ($_FILES[ 'userfile'] as $key=>$value{ 
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($value);
  }
?>
```

My html code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>file input click() demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="html5java.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
<a href="javascript:doClick()">Select some files</a>

        <div id="fileList"></div>
        <form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*"
            style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Images">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that php multiple files aren't stored as $_FILES['userfile'][x]['name'], etc. they are stored as $_FILES['userfile']['name']['x'].

So the best way is usually to loop over the files array and reorder the array to a more logical pattern. A function like below works pretty well for converting it to how you expect it to work (taken from the 2nd comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

```
<?php
    public static function fixGlobalFilesArray($files) {
        $ret = array();

        if(isset($files['tmp_name']))
        {
            if (is_array($files['tmp_name']))
            {
                foreach($files['name'] as $idx => $name)
                {
                    $ret[$idx] = array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$idx],
                        'size' => $files['size'][$idx],
                        'type' => $files['type'][$idx],
                        'error' => $files['error'][$idx]
                    );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $ret = $files;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($files as $key => $value)
            {
                $ret[$key] = self::fixGlobalFilesArray($value);
            }
        }

        return $ret;
    }
?>
```